# Is everything in Python castable to a string?

Tags: python, string, casting, type-conversion, theory

I'm trying to find an example of something in Python that can't be cast to a string.

```
>>> str(None)
'None'
>>> str(False)
'False'
>>> str(5)
'5'
>>> str(object)
"<class 'object'>"
>>> class Test:
...     pass
...
>>> str(Test)
"<class '__main__.Test'>"
>>> str(Test())
'<__main__.Test object at 0x7f7e88a13630>'
```

Is there anything the entire Python universe that cannot be cast to **str**?

Comment: Read about the `__str__` magic method.

Comment: Evey python ovject inherits from `object` which defined a `__str__` so for practical purposes, yes. Note, "cast" is a loosely defined term. But it connotes a specific thing in low-level, statically typed languages like C. IMO it isn't a good term to use in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) documentation:

```
The default implementation defined by the built-in type object
calls object.__repr__().
```

and `object.__repr__` prints object name and address (at least in cpython). That's where your output `'<__main__.Test object at 0x7f7e88a13630>'` comes from. A class would have to override `__str__` and raise an exception (or have a bug) to fail. There is little reason to do this and you'd be hard-pressed to find one that wasn't built to purpose.

Comment: So everything is castable to str unless you override the `__str__` method.

Comment: Yes, and even then you'd have to be crazy not to implement a `__str__` that returns a string. You could write a class with an `__init__` that wipes the hard drive. That wouldn't be very nice either.

Comment: @sneilan Or unless you don't define `__str__` at all but do override the `__repr__` method to do other than return a string.

Answer (score 4):

> Is everything in Python castable to a string?

Nope!

```py
>>> class MyObject():
...     def __str__(self):
...         raise NotImplementedError("You can't string me!")
...
>>> str(MyObject())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __str__
NotImplementedError: You can't string me!
```

Comment: Cool! What classes that don't raise NotImplementedError in the  `__str__` method?

It seems like apart from creating a `__str__` method that raises an error, everything is castable to a string.

Comment: @sneilan since everything inherits from `object` and `object` defines a well-behaved (if mostly useless) `__str__`, there _are_ no objects that are badly-behaved that haven't defined their own bad behavior. I'm not aware of any stdlib types that throw errors when you try to stringify them (but they may exist!)